# Превращение repr-представления строки в нормальную строку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Допустим, есть файл, в котором записана строка вида:

```
"Hello World!\n"
```

Я эту строку читаю из файла как есть, в переменной в результате оказывается вот что:

```
'"Hello World!\\n"'
```

Как мне эту строку *наиболее просто* преобразовать в исходное "нормальное" представление (раскрыть кавычки, раскрыть escape-последовательности) без использования `eval`?

Раскрытие кавычек затруднений не вызывает, "хоть какое-то" решение для escape-последовательностей, в принципе, тоже есть (грубо говоря, пока в строке есть что-то из `'\\n'`, `'\\r'`, `'\\t'`, делать соответствующие замены), но хотелось бы максимально простого/короткого решения без нестандартных зависимостей (типа [parse](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse)).

Нужно решение для python3.

Для python2 подошло бы `'"Hello World!\\n"'.strip('"').decode("string-escape")`, но под python3 у строки нет метода `decode`, а метод `decode` класса `bytes` не раскрывает escape-последовательности (или я что-то не так делаю).

Comment: а что мешает сделать так: `print((b'%s' % line).decode('unicode_escape'))`? Вашу строку отформатировало как и должно

Comment: @BOPOH, у вас Python 3.5 скорее всего, у меня пока что 3.4.

Comment: А вот так сработало: line.encode().decode('unicode_escape')

Comment: ой, я че-то думал у меня 3 по дефолту стоит, т.е. я на 2.7 проверял. На 3 это не сработает. Зато вот так: `bytes(line, 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')` на *Python 3.2.3* работает нормально

Comment: @BOPOH, все бы хорошо, но в ТЗ внезапно врываются кириллические строки, на которых это решение не работает, в итоге получается что-то типа `'Ð\x9fÑ\x80Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ\x82!\n'` (в оригинале было "Привет!\n")

Comment: а `line.encode('cp1252', 'backslashreplace').decode('unicode-escape')` подойдет? для русского вроде работает

Comment: @BOPOH, это работает, и скорее всего будет работать не только с кириллицей, если в decode ту же кодировку указать. Но что-то чем дальше в лес, тем больше на магию похоже, и вариант с `replace` уже кажется не таким уж плохим)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следует рассмотреть возможно ли исправить сохранение данных, чтобы избежать использования `repr()` при записи текста: пишите текст напрямую, выбросив `repr()` вызов, или используйте JSON формат — оба варианта являются эффективными и более переносимыми.

Если входной формат нельзя изменить, то можно использовать [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ast

text = ast.literal_eval(text_repr) # where text_repr = '"Привет!\\n"'
```

Comment: Вот за функцию спасибо, так и думал, что должно быть что-то из коробки) Формат данных изменить не получится, у меня свой велосипед по обработке файлов .pot/.po ([gettext](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext)). Для вывода использую, правда, не `repr()` (т.к. нужны двойные кавычки всегда, и прочие нюансы), но `ast.literal_eval()`, похоже, мне как раз подойдет.

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент использую такой вариант:

```
def unescape_string(s):
    return strip_once(s, '"')\
           .replace(r'\\', '\\')\
           .replace(r'\t', '\t')\
           .replace(r'\r', '\r')\
           .replace(r'\n', '\n')\
           .replace(r'\"', '\"')
```

Также можно использовать что-то вроде того, что предложил [BOPOH](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5079/bopoh):

```
line.encode(codepage, 'backslashreplace').decode(codepage, 'unicode-escape')
```

где вместо `codepage` по идее можно подставить любую кодировку (проверено на вариантах `ascii`, `cp1251`, `cp1252`, `latin`, `utf-8`), пример:

```
>>> ('Привет!\\n').encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace').decode('ascii', 'unicode-escape')
'Привет!\n'
```