# Как конвертировать string в list?

Tags: python, массивы, list

Например:
    
`s = '[(1,2),(3,4)]'`
Нужно перевести в:
    
`arr = [(1,2),(3,4)]`
Как сделать это используя наименее затратный способ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть специальная функция [`literal_eval()` из модуля `ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval), в каком-то смысле она обратна функции `repr()`:

```
import ast
s = '[(1,2),(3,4)]'
arr = ast.literal_eval(s)
print(arr)
```

Вывод:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4)]
```

Узнал о ней из ответа от [jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs) в моем вопросе: [Превращение repr-представления строки в нормальную строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/514484/1365).

Comment: Как обычно, хотелось бы узнать, за что минус?

Comment: Я бы лайкнул, ибо мне помогло. Но нет 15 рейтинга

Comment: @СтаниславБобокало если нельзя входной формат поменять, то это правильный ответ (хотя если входной формат ограничить, то можно более быстрый код написать)